# Facebook IA tracker down: replacement?

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-articles

www.ia-tracker.fbsbx.com/instant_article_test has been down for several days now. And it is impossible to debug Facebook IA articles.

```
www.ia-tracker.fbsbx.com/instant_article_test?url=<share-url>
```

What is everyone using as an alternative?

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says you can't ask this question here.

Comment: This returns an SSL certificate for *.facebook.com, so the browser blocks you from accessing the domain. File a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/, and ask them to please fix this.

Comment: Ya, thats what im getting to. Was just wondering if anyone had found an alternative